# Google Analytics in MVC4 ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I want to implement Google Analytics in my MVC4 ASP.net application. I had gone through so many link but not getting exact starting of it. Please help me for step by step implementation of Google Analytics in MVC4 ASP.net.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832711/implementing-google-analytics-in-mvc4-c

Comment: I want an example which will help me to use google analytics api for tracking complete access and statics of my website.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Comment: @DaImTo I have install GoogleAnalyticsTracker.MVC4 after that what should i do

Comment: Contact the person that made the third party tool to access Google Analytics (GoogleAnalyticsTracker.MVC4) or use Google's tools to do it which I linked.

Comment: All you really need is: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/